# InteliJ complaining about JHipster project files on open, until files opened or recompiled

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster

IJ Idea 2019.3.1 Ultimate, JH 6.6.

Have a microservices project with 3 microservices and a gateway. All OK except for one microservices module which keeps coming up with spurious errors on a handful of files. These go away if the files are opened one by one, or the module recompiled / cleaned with mvn, however come back inevitably. Is there any flag / full clean I can do to solve this?

Comment: Do you use any special plugins for JHipster? What error do you get, please add screenshots describing the exact issue.

Comment: Nothing special plugin wise,  screenshot: [link](https://imgur.com/gQN8NXs), errors are libs, like : Error:(4, 1) java: package org.springframework.data.jpa.repository does not exist
Error:(5, 38) java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
Error:(13, 42) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class JpaRepository
Error:(13, 70) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class JpaSpecificationExecutor
Error:(12, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Repository

Comment: All dependencies, target paths (replacing the module name), and other settings look exactly the same fo each module.

Comment: Looks like you are using Java 9 modules. Do you have these dependencies added in pom.xml with the `compile` scope? A project to check would be helpful. Make also sure you are using Java 9 compatible spring-boot and JPA libraries.